# What is callback in JavaScript means?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, arguments, asynccallback

hello friends
I am a little bit confused in js callback function and arguments of it.

Can someone to clarify this code to me(**only about callback function and arguments**)?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
 var allUserData = [];

 function logStuff(userData) { 
  if (typeof userData === 'string') { 
       console.log(userData); 
  } else if (typeof userData === "object") { 
      for (var item in userData) { 
            console.log(item + ": " + userData[item]); 
      }
  }
}
function getInput(options, callback) { 
  allUserData.push(options);
  callback(options); //What is that?
}
getInput({ name: 'Rich', speciality: 'JavaScript' }, logStuff); //How that's work?
```

Comment: It is a reference to the function that you pass in and it gets called when it is ready.

Comment: `callback(options)` invokes the function in the variable called `callback` which is passed as an argument containing the function `logStuff`, so `logStuff` is called and receives `options` as its argument.